# Using Dictionary to Pass Variables from Class to Class

Tags: python, class, dictionary, tkinter

I have been working on a Tkinter application for two days and I can't figure out how to pass information from one frame to another.

I tried to use a dictionary to do this

```
keys = ['key1','key2','key3']
result_dict = dict.fromkeys(keys)

class Class1():

    .......

    def updateDict(self):

        ####Do Calculations here

        result_dict['key1'] = newvalue
        result_dict['key2'] = new_key2_value
        result_dict['key3'] new_key3_value

class Class2():

    ......

    print result_dict['key3']
```

Basically, I initialize a dict outside of all the classes, then update it in my first class, then try to call the updated dict in my second class.  However, it keeps pointing to the first Dict with the None types in it.

I've been trying to fix this for hours.  So extremely frustrating.  What am I doing wrong? It's not throwing an error just printing None as the result.

Edit:  Here is my Full Code for this problem.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)

keys = ['Month','Year','Site','Operator','Amount','Value','Field']
result_dict = dict.fromkeys(keys)


def combine_funcs(*funcs):
    def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
        for f in funcs:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
    return combined_func


class Database(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        ###Sets the Window title
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self,"Database Searcher")
        ###Container is our Frame
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        ###Sets where this is
        container.pack(side="top", fill ="both", expand = True)
        ###Setting Row Attributes
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight =1)
        #Makes a Dictionary for adding more Frames
        self.frames = {}
        ###Main Page Frame
        for F in (MainPage,ResultPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = "nsew")
        ###Shows the main frame
        self.show_frame(MainPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class MainPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ####Init the Frame
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        self.data_selection =[]
        self.operator =[]
        self.data_value=[]
        self.year_value = []
        self.site_value =[]
        self.mon_value= []

        ###Label the Page as Main Page
        label = tk.Label(self, text ="Fill out the Information Below", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack()
        ###Create a Month Dropdown Menu
        monList = ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12')
        self.mon_field = tk.StringVar()
        monMenu = ttk.OptionMenu(self,self.mon_field, 'Month', *monList)
        monMenu.pack(side="top")
        ####Make an Entry for Year Data
        self.year_field = tk.StringVar(self, value = 'Enter Year')
        yearEntry = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable = self.year_field )
        yearEntry.pack()

        ###Sites
        siteList  = ('KMCI','KMKC','KCOU','KSTJ','KJEF','KSGF','KSTL')
        self.site_field = tk.StringVar()
        siteOptionMenu = ttk.OptionMenu(self, self.site_field,'Site',*siteList)
        siteOptionMenu.pack()

        ###Our dataList tuple for the dataList Option Menu
        dataList = ('High Temp','Low Temp','Precipitation','Snowfall', 'Snow Depth')
        ###Need to make a SringVar for the Menu ( this is how the .get() method works
        self.data_field = tk.StringVar()
        optionMenu2 = ttk.OptionMenu(self, self.data_field ,dataList[0],*dataList)
        ###Pack it and add it!
        optionMenu2.pack(side ='left')
        #####Operator Option Menu
        operatorList = ('Equal To','Greater Than','Less Than','Greater Than or Equal To',
                      'Less Than or Equal To')
        self.operator_field = tk.StringVar()
        optionMenu1 = ttk.OptionMenu(self,self.operator_field,operatorList[0],*operatorList)
        optionMenu1.pack(side ='left')

        ###Make a Entry text box for inputting the Values
        self.value_field = tk.StringVar(self, value = 'Enter Value Here')
        entry1 = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable = self.value_field)
        entry1.pack(side ="left", padx = 5)
        ###Add a Buttom commanded to databaseCalc Formula that makes
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = 'Get Data!', command = combine_funcs(self.databaseCalc, lambda: controller.show_frame(ResultPage)))
        button1.pack()

    def databaseCalc(self):
        data_selection = self.data_field.get()
        operator = self.operator_field.get()
        data_value = int(self.value_field.get())
        year_value = int(self.year_field.get())
        site_value = self.site_field.get()
        mon_value = int(self.mon_field.get())

        df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Michael/Desktop/Daily Data Proc/' + site_value +'.csv')

        data = (df[data_selection]).as_matrix()
        month =  (df['MONTH']).as_matrix()
        year = (df['YEAR']).as_matrix()

        if operator == 'Equal To':
            indc = np.where((data == data_value) & (month == mon_value) & (year == year_value))
            temp = data[indc]
            self.amount = (np.ones_like(temp)).sum()
        elif operator == 'Greater Than':
            indc = np.where((data > data_value) & (month == mon_value) & (year == year_value))
            temp = data[indc]
            self.amount = (np.ones_like(temp)).sum()        
        elif operator == 'Less Than':
            indc = np.where((data < data_value) & (month == mon_value) & (year == year_value))
            temp = data[indc]
            self.amount = (np.ones_like(temp)).sum()
        elif operator == 'Greater Than or Equal To':
            indc = np.where((data >= data_value) & (month == mon_value) & (year == year_value))
            temp = data[indc]
            self.amount = (np.ones_like(temp)).sum()
        elif operator == 'Less than or Equal To':
            indc = np.where((data <= data_value) & (month == mon_value) & (year == year_value))
            temp = data[indc]
            self.amount = (np.ones_like(temp)).sum()
##        result_dict.update('Month' : self.mon_field, 'Year': self.year_field, 'Site': self.site_field,
##                           'Operator': self.operator, 'Amount' = self.amount, 'Value' = self.data_value, 'Field' = self.data_selection)
        result_dict['Month'] = mon_value
        result_dict['Year'] = year_value
        result_dict['Site'] = site_value
        result_dict['Operator'] = operator
        result_dict['Amount'] = self.amount
        result_dict['Value'] = data_value
        result_dict['Field'] = data_selection




class ResultPage(tk.Frame):


    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        ###Create a Label with the results that we would like to display
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text = str(result_dict['Amount']), font = LARGE_FONT)
        label1.pack()


        ###Create a Button to go Backwards
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text = 'Run Another Query', command = lambda: controller.show_frame(MainPage))
        button2.pack()



app =  Database()
app.mainloop()
```

databaseCalc() inside of MainPage is where I update the dict that I initiate in the first few lines of code.  I then want to use those updated values in class ResultPage and display them in the window.  This code works, but lists None as the label on ResultPage

Comment: Do you ever call `Class1().updateDict()` function?

Comment: No but when I print result_dict['key3']  outside of Class2 (so in the shell or just as a line outside of the class, I get the right value.  So the dict is updating, but in Class2...it keeps pointing to the dict with None type entries

Comment: No? If you never call `Class1().updateDict()` as @Selcuk asked about, I don't see how it could have the values you're expecting, either outside `Class2` or inside it (unless you mutate `result_dict` somewhere else).

Comment: Please post a minimal _working_ code that displays this exact behaviour when run. We are only guessing here with partial, non-working code.

Comment: I have added the code @Selcuk

Comment: It can be something to do with your `combined_funcs`. Are you sure it processes the functions in the order they are passed?

Comment: I switched the order and it did not work, so I don't think it has to do with the combined_funcs.  I'm pretty sure it's that when the __init__ funciton of ResultPage class is ran it is pointing to the dict with the None values.  When I update it, the ResultPage __init__ method doesn't point to the updated dict.